# Scala vectorization API

Tags: scala, vectorization, hpc

Is there any Scala API for high performance vectorized computation as in numpy for Python ?

For instance, for summing up two (very large) `Array`,

```
vect.sum( Array(1,2,3,...), Array(10,11,12,...) ) == Array(11,13,15,...)
```

Comment: This is so much the "asking SO to recommend" reason for being off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are many projects:

http://www.spiral.net/software/spiral-scala.html[1](http://www.spiral.net/software/spiral-scala.html)

In general, scala-lms and delite deal with the very problem of "abstraction without regret".

https://scala-lms.github.io/

and

http://stanford-ppl.github.io/Delite/

Also, don't forget that you are on the JVM so java has some nice libraries, e.g.

http://jblas.org/

Answer (score 1):

Breeze is one library that aims for that: https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze

It's one of three projects under the umbrella-project ScalaNLP (http://www.scalanlp.org/)